# how to control text area scroll with buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text area, and I have two buttons.

I want to scroll 10px horizontally (to the right) when the button is clicked, and to the left (also 10px) when the second one is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by text area?
Is it the `<textarea>` elemnt or do you just have a div or a span with some text in it?
in any case if you just want to scroll contents left or right, you might want to use `scrollLeft` property on a container.
`element.scrollLeft += 10;` will scroll to the right.
`element.scrollLeft -= 10;` will scroll to the left.

If you give a more clearer description of what you are trying to do, then maybe people here can help you out better.

Answer (score 0):

Possible using the doScroll method.

http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/method-doscroll.shtml

Comment: @Speransky Danil How else would mind to get this task done? You need some kind of scripting language and JavaScript is the most popular…